# Swift 2.0 LocationManager is nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have problem with `LocationManager` in swift 2.0. Its my Location Class :

*

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
class Location : NSObject,  CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?


    func locationManagerStart() {

        if locationManager == nil {

            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager?.delegate = self;
            locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }

        locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    func locationManagerStop() {

        locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    //MARK: CLLocationManagerDelegate

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {

        coordinate = newLocation.coordinate

    }
```

*

I create object in this class in `AppDelegate` :

```
let location = Location()
```

and start location when my app became active:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {


        location.locationManagerStart()

    }
```

Later in my code I need to check if i have access to location. I am suer i have because i have location on in iPhone and I accepted use my location :

```
 func haveAccessToLocation() -> Bool {

        if (coordinate?.latitude) != nil {

            return true

        }else {

            return false
        }

    }
```

My `cordinate?.latitude/longitude` is nil and my `locationManager` is nil too  and i dont know why

Comment: You are running this on Simulator? - test it on a real device.

Comment: did you check didUpdateToLocation to getting called or not

Comment: is it displaying popup to enable location when you run your app first time?

Comment: @Fennec - I am running on iphone 6s plus.

Comment: @SunnyShah - I will check

Comment: @JigarTarsariya - Yes it is

Comment: Ok first you should try to get location in appDelegate to make sure that about your code is running.

Comment: Ok my debug : 
(lldb) po location.coordinate
nil

(lldb) po location.locationManager
▿ Optional<CLLocationManager>
  - Some : <CLLocationManager: 0x101174cb0>

Maybe coordinates are nil because i got Location Popup after my code in appdelegate is running

Comment: @Rob it could be nice idea. I create another  let position = Location() and when i am checking AccessToLocation It might be a different object than the one on which I created manager

Comment: Yep, that would do it. Reference the `Location` object in your app delegate (or make it a singleton). Definitely don't instantiate it twice.

Comment: I dont want to use singletons so i need to think how to reference to the Location in my AppDelegate

Comment: If you keep calling down to your appDelegate to get the location manager, you are effectively using the appDelegate as a singleton.

Comment: Okey Guys. I will try , thanks a lot for your help :) Have a nice day

Comment: Thanks @Rob again. I will use it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. If you want just say it as Answer. I will choose your answer as best :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> My `coordinate?.latitude/longitude` is `nil` ...

If `locationManager` is not `nil`, but `coordinate` is, that simply means that you're checking for the `coordinate` before the location manager successfully had a chance to retrieve the location. It can take a few seconds.

> ... and my `locationManager` is `nil`, too.

If you called `locationManagerStart`, but you later checked `locationManager` and it was `nil`, that means that you might have two instances of `Location()` in your code. Make sure you always reference the instance created by the app delegate and refrain from other references to `Location()`.

As an aside, instantiating `Location` in `applicationDidBecomeActive` can cause multiple instances in certain cases, too (because if the app becomes inactive and active again, you'll instantiate it again). I'd suggest starting the location services in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. I don't think that's the problem here, but be aware of this issue.